# Validating at least one child checkbox, corresponding to a checked element of a checkbox array

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, checkbox

I have jQuery validation implemented on a form which has a set of nested checkbox groups. The main checkbox is an element of a checkbox array. If a main checkbox is checked, at least on the child checkboxes must be checked. The child checkboxes are in a div and the id is generated using the value of the main checkbox.

The following code works, but I am pretty sure this can be simplified a lot more. I would request the experts here to make this better. Thanks in advance.

```
$.validator.addMethod("atLeastOne", function(value, element) {
    var flag = true;
    $('.mod_check').each(function(){ 
    if (this.checked){
        if($('#actions_'+$(this).val()).find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 0)
           flag = false;
    }
});
return flag;
}, "Select at least one of the actions");
```

Comment: can you share the html also

Answer (score 0):

One way of improvement is to break from $.each when u encounter any one unchecked child check box.

```
$.validator.addMethod("atLeastOne", function(value, element) {
var flag = true;
$('.mod_check').each(function(){ 
if (this.checked){
    if($('#actions_'+$(this).val()).find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 0)
       flag = false;
       return;
}
});
return flag;
}, "Select at least one of the actions");
```

So the remaining iterations are not required.

Comment: You have a good point, but I was looking for something to loop through just the checked checkboxes of the main checkbox array, but I was having some issues with that. Any suggestion in that direction? Thank you.

Comment: The problem may be due to the selector, if u cud post HTML also it wud be helpful.

Comment: Now each is looping through all the checkboxes whether they are checked or not. We can loop through just the checked ones, right? It didn't work for me.